# Can TomEE load a filter class that is deployed in a war?

Tags: jakarta-ee, dependencies, servlet-filters, apache-tomee

I have added a filter to a RESTful web application. This application uses JavaEE 6 and is deployed in an Apache TomEE server 1.7.3.

The filter class that I have added looks like this:

```
package com.company.filter;

import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

public class LoggingFilter implements Filter {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger("std");

    @Override
    public void init(final FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {

        LOG.info("Initializing filter");
    }

    public void doFilter(final ServletRequest request, final ServletResponse response, final FilterChain filterChain)
        throws IOException, ServletException {

        LOG.info("Processing a request...");

        // filter logic
    }

    public void destroy() {
        LOG.info("Destroying filter");
    }
}
```

The web.xml (specific to the application, and deployed inside the application war), looks like this:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>LoggingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.company.filter.LoggingFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>LoggingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

I have not modified the main web.xml in the conf folder.

When I deploy the application, and start up the TomEE server, I see the following error in catalina.log:

```
SEVERE: Unable to deploy collapsed ear in war     StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/vw-ws-rest]
org.apache.openejb.OpenEJBException: Unable to load servlet filter class: com.company.filter.LoggingFilter: com.company.filter.LoggingFilter
at org.apache.openejb.config.AnnotationDeployer$ProcessAnnotatedBeans.deploy(AnnotationDeployer.java:2141)
at org.apache.openejb.config.AnnotationDeployer$ProcessAnnotatedBeans.deploy(AnnotationDeployer.java:1843)
at org.apache.openejb.config.AnnotationDeployer.deploy(AnnotationDeployer.java:360)
```

Note: the package and class name are correct.

If I package the filter class in a separate jar, and put that jar in the libs directory, then the application does load the filter class, and it works fine.

But I dont want to have generate another artifact, and deploy that artifact, as its makes the deployment process more complicated.

My questions are: cant TomEE load a filter that is contained in the application war? and if it can, then what am I doing wrong? (it looks like TomEE simply cant see the filter class when initializing itself)

Comment: The error message says that the class is named `com.company.filter.LoggingFilter`. The web.xml says that the class is named `com.company.LoggingFilter`. The posted code of the class doesn't have any package statement. Which of the three is true? Is everything coherent? Post real code and error messages, otherwise it's impossible to diagnose what the actual problem might be. Also, tell us where the .class file is in the war, and post the complete stack trace of the exception.

Comment: But you still haven't posted the complete stack trace, and still haven't said where the .class file is located in the war.

Comment: Hi, in the end, after trying this for some time, its worked for me. I dont know exactly what my problem was, but I guess I had some silly mistake. The answer to my question is that, its possible to use a filter, that is deployed within a war (the server extracts the classes, and as long as its in the folder, then it works)